# Password protect Joomla URL via .htaccess

Tags: url, joomla, passwords

I would like to learn how to password protect a single search engine friendly URL in Joomla using `.htaccess`.

Example of URL I'd like to protect:

```
http://example.com/home/hidden-stuff
```

This is a search friendly Joomla URL, so it's not a real path URL.

Comment: You need to provide some more details... like why? what have you tried? Is the built-in ACL in Joomla not good enough? It'll probably help if you tell us which version of Joomla! as well.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it would just be setting the access for that item/menu item to Registered or Special. Then anyone would need to log in to Joomla before they'd be able to see it.

If you need to use .htaccess protection, give this a shot: [Password protection for a single .htaccess rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269079/htaccess-password-protect-for-a-single-rewrited-seo-friendlyurl?rq=1)