# Password protection for a single .htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, prestashop, .htpasswd

I need a password protection for a single site. This is a seo friendly url:
The default path is:

```
http://www.website-url.com/index.php?id_cms=xx&controller=cms
```

and here is the seo url:

```
http://www.website-url.com/content/xx-login
```

I have already the .htaccess and .htpasswd, but how to specify rewriting in .htaccess only for this url? I tried this:

```
<filesMatch "http://www.website-url.com/content/xx-login">
IndexIgnore .htaccess .htpasswd
AuthUserFile /absolut_path/.htpasswd
AuthName "Login"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
</filesMatch>
```

I'm using Prestashop.

Comment: You need to look into mod_rewrite if you're trying to re-write URLs

Answer (score 2):

FilesMatch doesn't work that way, you could try using SetEnvIf to bypass the Auth unless the URI is something specific (which is what I gather you are trying to do):

```
IndexIgnore .htaccess .htpasswd

SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/content/xx-login" SECURED

# enforce auth if SECURED
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Login"
AuthUserFile /absolut_path/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from env=!SECURED
Satisfy any
```